# How do I stop my blog from pinging back itself?

Tags: pingbacks

I connect a lot of my posts to my new ones, and that is probably why I keep getting self pingbacks. Besides a plugin, is there a script I can use to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this by putting code in functions.php in your theme.

```
function no_self_ping( &$links ) {
$home = get_option( 'home' );
foreach ( $links as $l => $link )
    if ( 0 === strpos( $link, $home ) )
        unset($links[$l]);
}
add_action( 'pre_ping', 'no_self_ping' );
```

Hope this helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I used a no trackback plugin for a few years (and I forget which one, there are a few available); it did seem silly to ping myself. Then I decided it was more like a way to connect posts, and stopped using it.

For a small amount of code, it's probably not much of a tradeoff between plugin or to try the code above. As an alternative to changing the theme, for a few projects especially on multisite where I do not want to alter themes others might use, I have used the [My Custom Functions plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/) to add small bits of code w/o having to mod functions.php